# Descobrir a semana do mês e lidar com casos especiais

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou tentando fazer uma função que identifique a qual semana do mês pertence determinado dia e, caso o dia primeiro seja no fim de uma semana, que ele seja contabilizado como dia da semana anterior, ou seja, a última do mês anterior. E caso os últimos dias estejam no inicio de uma semana, eles entrem para a semana do mês subsequente. Dessa forma, não haveríam semanas com menos de 7 dias.
Consegui fazer algo utilizando as formulas SE, E, OU e Dia.DA.SEMANA. Porém, não consigo fazer que, ao agrupar o dia 1 como dia da quinta semana do mês anteiror, a semana 2 passe a ser considerada semana 1, a 3 como 2 e assim por diante.
Segue abaixo a fórmula que criei:

```
=SE(OU(E(OU(DIA.DA.SEMANA(A2)=5;DIA.DA.SEMANA(A2)=6;DIA.DA.SEMANA(A2)=7);MÊS(A2-1)<>MÊS(A2));E(OU(DIA.DA.SEMANA(A2)=6;DIA.DA.SEMANA(A2)=7);MÊS(A2-2)<>MÊS(A2)));5;SE(OU(E(DIA.DA.SEMANA(A2)<4;MÊS(A2+1)<>MÊS(A2));E(DIA.DA.SEMANA(A2)<3;MÊS(A2+3)<>MÊS(A2)));1;NÚMSEMANA(A2)-NÚMSEMANA(DATA(ANO(A2);MÊS(A2);1))+1))
```

Caso tenham alguma solução (por VBA ou por fórmulas do excel mesmo) ajudaria muito!

Comment: Trabalhar com dias de semana é muito complicado, principalmente na virada do ano... Para isso existe a ISO 8601-1:2019, sugiro utilizar este modelo. Se quiser ver como o Ron de Bruin faz em VBA veja [este link](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s8/win001.htm). A partir do Excel 2013 existe a função [ISO](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.isoweeknum)

Comment: Entendo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!